# Why does Membership.GeneratePassword give me Nonalphanumeric when I specifiy 0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, forgot-password, non-alphanumeric

I used 
    Membership.GeneratePassword(10, 0) 
in my C# application code. The GeneratePassword method Generates a random password of the specified length.

The second argument specifies the the minimum number of non-alphanumeric characters (such as @, #, !, %, &, and so on) in the generated password.

I don't want any non-alphanumeric characters so I specified zero.
However, it still fails because I got a password with Nonalphanumeric content when I execute 
    Membership.GeneratePassword(10, 0)

Lg|1-F;?a4

Why the pipe( | ) and the hypen( - ) and semicolon and the question mark?

Comment: Unfortunately, `GeneratePassword` specifies a minimum ,not  maximum number of non alpha characters. You'll need to roll your own - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625150/membership-generate-password-alphanumeric-only-password)

Comment: Why are non-alphanumeric characters an issue for you?

Comment: Some of the users that use the web application have low-level computer skills.  They don't know what key to press for pipe( | ) ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Some of the users that use the web application have low-level computer skills. They don't know what key to press for pipe( | )

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this workaround below, which uses regex to strip out non-alphanumeric characters and replaces them with a random number.

```
String newPassword = Membership.GeneratePassword(8, 0); //Second arg only guarantees a minimum number (not maximum) number of alphanumeric characters.
Random rng = New Random();
newPassword = Regex.Replace(newPassword, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", rng.Next(0, 10).ToString());
```